# Get a list of 2013 Workflows

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, powershell

I'm trying to get a list of 2013 workflows on our 2013 on prem farm using PowerShell.  I'm using the script found here, https://sharepointpixels.wordpress.com/2016/06/23/sharepoint-list-of-2013-workflows/.  But when I run it I get this error,

Exception calling "EnumerateSubscriptionsByList" with "1" argument(s): "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation."

On this line, $subscriptions = $wfsService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList($spList.ID)

Comment: The PS script at the link loops all the web applications, and there's a chance that the account executing the script might not have permissions to all web applications. I would test the script targeting a single list first to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, the powershell works fine in my farm.

To be safe, please test again with farm account who has full control on all lists.

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/account-permissions-and-security-settings-in-sharepoint-2013#farm-administrator-user--account